# How can I put contents from an input file into two separate arrays?

Tags: c++

For a homework problem, we are assigned an input file titled "options.txt". The contents of the file contain an option (the grand scheme of the assignment is we have a user  pick a car model and then pick different options they want to add onto their car) and a price on each line. There are 15 options and therefore 15 prices. I need to put the prices and options into their own separate arrays so I will be able to use them later in the program, but I'm not sure how to do this.

I initially thought I would be able to do something like `instream >> price; prices[i] = price; i++;` and the same for the options. But there are multiple words for most of the options so I don't think this will work.

I don't have any code to show for this yet so any help is greatly appreciated.

Input file contents:

```
5000 Leather Seats
1000 DVD System
800 10 Speakers
1400 Navigation System
500 CarPlay
500 Android Auto
2000 Lane Monitoring
800 3/36 Warranty
999 6/72 Warranty
1500 Dual Climate
225 Body Side Molding
49 Cargo Net
87 Cargo Organizer
700 450W Audio
1000 Heated Seats
```

Comment: If it is always "[price] [item]" one per line, then read the price as you suggested. For the item, use the `getline` function.

Comment: @ChrisMM post an answer with this idea :-) I'd upvote

Answer (score 0):

If it is always "[price] [item]" one per line, then read the price as you suggested. For the item, use the `getline` function

For example:

```cpp
instream >> prices[i]; // Get the price
std::getline( instream, items[i] ); // Get anything left on the line (including spaces, but not \n)
++i;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
  std::string item;
  double price;

  std::ifstream file{"options.txt"};

  while (file >> price && std::getline(file >> std::ws, item)) {
    std::cout << item << ":" << price << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Note the use of `std::ws` in `std::getline(file >> std::ws, item)` - it is required to skip the ' ' character that is next in the stream.

You can also get the whole line and split it using [std::substr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
  std::string line;

  std::ifstream file{"options.txt"};

  while (std::getline(file, line)) {
    std::string item = line.substr(line.find_first_of(' ', 0) + 1);
    double price = std::stod(line.substr(0, line.find_first_of(' ', 0)));

    std::cout << item << ":" << price << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```